# Windows 7 Upgrade from an OEM disc

Tags: windows-7, installation, upgrade

I recently bought a new laptop with Windows 7 Home Premium and a Windows 7 Pro Upgrade key.  It also comes with a cavalcade of bloatware.  I would like to start with a fresh install of Windows.

I understand that I can upgrade to W7Pro using the option in the Home Premium Start menu.  However, I also own a Windows 7 Pro OEM installation disc from another computer.  Can I use this Windows 7 Pro OEM disc to install Windows, and when it asks me for my key, provide the upgrade key purchased?  Or am i required to install Home Premium first and then apply my upgrade key?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use an OEM disk and then provide your code.